# Find the sites that have been granted access to the Gmail account

Tags: google-account

So I've been trying to find out how you can see what apps and **sites** I have used my gmail for. I feel like this used to be possible, but all the answers I've gotten always lead me to a dead end where I can only see what apps I've used my gmail for. Where can I see the sites? I'm not interested in the apps, only the sites... The usual rout of account, account settings, apps and sites with acces doesn't work anymore.